# What is the configuration file of MariaDB?

Tags: debian, mariadb

I'm using stand-alone database on Debian, and I'm new to MariaDB. 
In MySQL, I used to deal with only one `my.cnf` which contained all relevant parameters that I needed.

Here, in MariaDB 10, there are dozens of them:

```
/etc/mysql# tree
.
├── conf.d
│   ├── mysql.cnf
│   └── mysqldump.cnf
├── debian.cnf
├── debian-start
├── mariadb.cnf
├── mariadb.conf.d
│   ├── 50-client.cnf
│   ├── 50-mysql-clients.cnf
│   ├── 50-mysqld_safe.cnf
│   └── 50-server.cnf
├── my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
└── my.cnf.fallback
```

I need to modify parameters like `max_connections`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `long_query_time` to register slow queries. I added them to `my.cnf` but then the server refused to restart.

So I'm wondering what file should I modify?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-overview/)?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I know the directives. Just don't know where to put them. And the docs does not help about this.

Comment: "don't know where to put them" - As I understand, it should be in the `[mariadb]` group.

Comment: I removed the [tag:mysql] tag because this is a question about MariaDB alone.

Comment: Also there may be things like `!includedir` in one of those files.

Answer (score 6):

To check which configuration files are processed by the server, just execute

`$ /path_to_mysqld/mysqld --help --verbose`

At the beginning of output you will find information about configuration files, e.g.

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Please note, that a setting might be overwritten, e.g. if /etc/my.cnf contains the value val=1, but ~/my.cnf contains val=3.

Since you mentioned that the server refused to start, you likely added your changes to the right file, but the settings are incorrect. In this case you should check the error log in your data directory.

Comment: this does not work with mariadb 10.5.18, I checked /etc/init.d and it does not have mysqld rather it has mariadb and when I tried `mariadb --help --verbose` it does include the information but at the top, so you can grep this information `mariadb --help --verbose | grep -A 1 'Default options'`